# How to authenticate Microsoft Speech to Text

Tags: curl, speech-recognition

I am trying to follow the `Curl` example to get the security token
This is not my actual subscription key.

```
curl -v -X POST "https://oxford-speech.cloudapp.net/token/issueToken" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Content-Length: 158" \
 -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=634c5496a8c6e63963cb9&client_secret=634c5496a8c6e63963cb9&scope=https://speech.platform.bing.com'
```

This command always returns:

> Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a
>   valid key for an active subscription.

Comment: And without content-length?

Comment: I tried it with a content length too. I don't know if I counted wrong but that didn't help.  This way returned a valid response from the service.

Comment: I wrote "without"

Comment: You are right. I get the valid server response without content length, using the curl example. Unfortunately, the response is my subscription key is not valid.

Comment: You need to remove content-length from the question text then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to look at the JavaScript, a C#, and the Curl examples to put this together.

First call should look like this:
curl -v -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 3e292398db944549913b2j1i23sadbd" --data "{}"

You will get back a long token. 
Add the long token to the call below by replacing <put long token here>

curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=smd&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&locale=en-US&device.os=wp7&version=3.0&format=json&instanceid=565D69FF-E928-4B7E-87DA-9A750B96D9E3&requestid=147f5563-e8c3-41b1-b2ea-039e24a7ae48" \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <put long token here>' \
-H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=16000' --data-binary @./outputfile.wav